# Use paramiko for executing bash commands in parallel

Tags: python, bash, parallel-processing, paramiko

I have a python script which I use to parse large amounts of data remotely.

The python scripts takes as argument the string I want to parse. In my current use case I am looking for multiple strings. To have this process execute faster I wanted to achieve parallelization.

So I followed the logic of the this command:

```
sleep 10 & sleep 12 & wait; sleep 20 & wait;
```

Basically what I do is construct a long command calling my parsing script for each of the strings I want to parse and I pass this command to paramiko `client.exec_command(cmd)`

An example command would look like:

```
python parseString.py *.txt -v Hello & parseString.py *.txt -v World & parseString.py *.txt -v Foo & parseString.py *.txt -v Bar & wait; python parseString.py *.txt -v Test & parseString.py *.txt -v Something & parseString.py *.txt -v Thing & parseString.py *.txt -v No & wait; parseString.py *.txt -v Yes & wait;
```

As you see I send 4 calls at most to not hog the machine. Also the scripts are running on the same files (not sure whether this could be a problem). When I check `htop` the scrips appear as `S`, so sleeping. I am not sure what could be the problem.

The final output file where I collect the output of the paramiko stdout reaches 59 MB, and the process hangs. Could it be the size that limits the scripts from finishing?

I do not want to create multiple ssh sessions to execute my script.

Comment: Can you tell us the status of the remote commands on the machine executing them? Can you also try passing a timeout to `client.exec_command` and see that it eventually returns?

Comment: The commands execute for ~4 seconds and their status on `htop` becomes `S` (S - interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)). I passed a timeout to `client.exec_command` but it did not return